# How to get django logs behind uwsgi?

Tags: django, uwsgi, fluentd

I am using uWSGI + Django, and I am using `fluent.handler.FluentHandler` as one of log handlers to send logs to `fluentd`.

On my local machine, I can get Django logs correctly with `runserver`.

When I run Django with uWSGI, I can only see request logs from uWSGI, no logs was sent to log handlers in Django.

Anyone can help about how to make log handlers receive Django logs?